# TypeScript не дружит с вложенностью?

Tags: visual-studio, angular2, typescript

Почему VS 2017 выдает предупреждения о том, что не найден модуль:

> TS:Cannot find module

, если путь полностью валидный:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
?

Ну и ругань на том, что декораторы- это экспериментальная фича:

> Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to
>   change in a future release

хотя в tsconfig.json прописано:   `"experimentalDecorators": true`

При всем при этом все успешно компилируется.

Может ли как-то вложенность оказывать влияние?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если да, то как это фиксить?

В компонентах уровня выше таких ошибок нет...

И такие предупреждения, появились, как я заметил, там, где есть JS файлы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

конфигурация TS'a:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: а путь к файлам в папке администратора? Если да то нужно менять пользователя

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk что вы подразумеваете под папкой "администратора"? Папку, которая находится в "C:\Users..." ? Все файлы имеют путь к модулям в папке с приложением.

Comment: если в "C:\Users\Администратор", или под другим пользователем (Вы - User1 путь - User2) то есть вероятность, что связано с доступами

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk, не, там ничего не хранится. Если бы проблемы с доступом были, тогда бы, наверное, не компилировалось бы...

Comment: не понял у вас путь к диску Е:/ ?

Comment: попробуйте положить node_modules в корень например С:/

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk ну да, к локальному node_modules проекта

Comment: читали [тут](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8812)

Comment: настроить tsconfig "exclude": ["node_modules"] или  просто перезапустить VS :)

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk, добавил, понаблюдаю.

Comment: однако, на экспериментальные декортаторы ругань не прекратилась.... хотя ключ стоит     "experimentalDecorators": true,

Comment: по декораторам это проблема VS https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25823

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk чет все равно говорит, что ошибки в модулях... Конфиг приложил в вопрос.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907164/experimental-support-for-decorators-visual-studio-2017 вот еще говорят  в  .csproj нужно добавить content. Пробовали?